# What is the fastest way to count elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, count, binning

In my models, one of the most repeated tasks to be done is counting the number of each element within an array. The counting is from a closed set, so I know there are `X` types of elements, and all or some of them populate the array, along with zeros that represent 'empty' cells. The array is not sorted in any way, and could by quite long (about 1M elements), and this task is done thousands of times during one simulation (which is also part of hundreds of simulations). The result should be a vector `r` of size `X`, so `r(k)` is the amount of `k` in the array.

#### Example:

For `X = 9`, if I have the following input vector:

```
v = [0 7 8 3 0 4 4 5 3 4 4 8 3 0 6 8 5 5 0 3]
```

I would like to get this result:

```
r = [0 0 4 4 3 1 1 3 0]
```

Note that I don't want the count of zeros, and that elements that don't appear in the array (like `2`) have a `0` in the corresponding position of the result vector (`r(2) == 0`).

What would be the **fastest** way to achieve this goal?

Comment: After your edit: why is the result vector of length 9? How am I supposed to know that `9` is a valid number that happens not to appear?

Comment: @Dev-iL I write: _"I know there are X types of elements"_, and then _"The result should be a vector in size X"_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The fastest method depend on the size of the array. For array smaller than 2<sup>14</sup> method 3 below (`accumarray`) is faster. For arrays larger than that method 2 below (`histcounts`) is better.

UPDATE: I tested this also with [implicit broadcasting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html), that was introduced in 2016b, and the results are almost equal to the `bsxfun` approach, with no significant difference in this method (relative to the other methods).

---

Let's see what are the available methods to perform this task. For the following examples we will assume `X` has `n` elements, from 1 to `n`, and our array of interest is `M`, which is a column array that can vary in size. Our result vector will be `spp`<sup>1</sup>, such that `spp(k)` is the number of `k`s in `M`. Although I write here about `X`, there is no explicit implementation of it in the code below, I just define `n = 500` and `X` is implicitly `1:500`.

#### The naive `for` loop

The most simple and straightforward way to cope this task is by a `for` loop that iterate over the elements in `X` and count the number of elements in `M` that equal to it:

```
function spp = loop(M,n)
spp = zeros(n,1);
for k = 1:size(spp,1);
    spp(k) = sum(M==k); 
end
end
```

This is off course not so smart, especially if only little group of elements from `X` is populating `M`, so we better look first for those that are already in `M`:

```
function spp = uloop(M,n)
u = unique(M); % finds which elements to count
spp = zeros(n,1);
for k = u(u>0).';
    spp(k) = sum(M==k); 
end
end
```

---

Usually, in MATLAB, it is advisable to take advantage of the built-in functions as much as possible, since most of the times they are much faster. I thought of 5 options to do so:

#### 1. The function [`tabulate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html)

The function `tabulate` returns a very convenient frequency table that at first sight seem to be the perfect solution for this task:

```
function tab = tabi(M)
tab = tabulate(M);
if tab(1)==0
    tab(1,:) = [];
end
end
```

The only fix to be done is to remove the first row of the table if it counts the `0` element (it could be that there are no zeros in `M`).

#### 2. The function [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html)

Another option that can be tweaked quite easily to our need it `histcounts`:

```
function spp = histci(M,n)
spp = histcounts(M,1:n+1);
end
```

here, in order to count all different elements between 1 to `n` separately, we define the edges to be `1:n+1`, so every element in `X` has it's own bin. We could write also `histcounts(M(M>0),'BinMethod','integers')`, but I already tested it, and it takes more time (though it makes the function independent of `n`).

#### 3. The function [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

The next option I'll bring here is the use of the function `accumarray`:

```
function spp = accumi(M)
spp = accumarray(M(M>0),1);
end
```

here we give the function `M(M>0)` as input, to skip the zeros, and use `1` as the `vals` input to count all unique elements.

#### 4. The function [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

We can even use binary operation `@eq` (i.e. `==`) to look for all elements from each type:

```
function spp = bsxi(M,n)
spp = bsxfun(@eq,M,1:n);
spp = sum(spp,1);
end
```

if we keep the first input `M` and the second `1:n` in different dimensions, so one is a column vector the other is a row vector, then the function compares each element in `M` with each element in `1:n`, and create a `length(M)`-by-`n` logical matrix than we can sum to get the desired result.

#### 5. The function [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html)

Another option, similar to the `bsxfun`, is to explicitly create the two matrices of all possibilities using the `ndgrid` function:

```
function spp = gridi(M,n)
[Mx,nx] = ndgrid(M,1:n);
spp = sum(Mx==nx);
end
```

then we compare them and sum over columns, to get the final result.

### Benchmarking

I have done a little test to find the fastest method from all mentioned above, I defined `n = 500` for all trails. For some (especially the naive `for`) there is a great impact of `n` on the time of execution, but this is not the issue here since we want to test it for a given `n`.

Here are the results:
[image: Timing hist]

We can notice several things:

1. Interestingly, there is a shift in the fastest method. For arrays smaller than 2<sup>14</sup> `accumarray` is the fastest. For arrays larger than 2<sup>14</sup> `histcounts` is the fastest.
2. As expected the naive `for` loops, in both versions are the slowest, but for arrays smaller than 2<sup>8</sup> the "unique & for" option is slower. `ndgrid` become the slowest in arrays bigger than 2<sup>11</sup>, probably because of the need to store very large matrices in memory.
3. There is some irregularity in the way `tabulate` works on arrays in size smaller than 2<sup>9</sup>. This result was consistent (with some variation in the pattern) in all the trials I conducted.

(the `bsxfun` and `ndgrid` curves are truncated because it makes my computer stuck in higher values, and the trend is quite clear already)

Also, notice that the y-axis is in log<sub>10</sub>, so a decrease in unit (like for arrays in size 2<sup>19</sup>, between `accumarray` and `histcounts`) means a 10-times faster operation.

I'll be glad to hear in the comments for improvements to this test, and if you have another, conceptually different method, you are most welcome to suggest it as an answer.

#### The code

Here are all the functions wrapped in a timing function:

```
function out = timing_hist(N,n)
M = randi([0 n],N,1);
func_times = {'for','unique & for','tabulate','histcounts','accumarray','bsxfun','ndgrid';
    timeit(@() loop(M,n)),...
    timeit(@() uloop(M,n)),...
    timeit(@() tabi(M)),...
    timeit(@() histci(M,n)),...
    timeit(@() accumi(M)),...
    timeit(@() bsxi(M,n)),...
    timeit(@() gridi(M,n))};
out = cell2mat(func_times(2,:));
end

function spp = loop(M,n)
spp = zeros(n,1);
for k = 1:size(spp,1);
    spp(k) = sum(M==k); 
end
end

function spp = uloop(M,n)
u = unique(M);
spp = zeros(n,1);
for k = u(u>0).';
    spp(k) = sum(M==k); 
end
end

function tab = tabi(M)
tab = tabulate(M);
if tab(1)==0
    tab(1,:) = [];
end
end

function spp = histci(M,n)
spp = histcounts(M,1:n+1);
end

function spp = accumi(M)
spp = accumarray(M(M>0),1);
end

function spp = bsxi(M,n)
spp = bsxfun(@eq,M,1:n);
spp = sum(spp,1);
end

function spp = gridi(M,n)
[Mx,nx] = ndgrid(M,1:n);
spp = sum(Mx==nx);
end
```

And here is the script to run this code and produce the graph:

```
N = 25; % it is not recommended to run this with N>19 for the `bsxfun` and `ndgrid` functions.
func_times = zeros(N,5);
for n = 1:N
    func_times(n,:) = timing_hist(2^n,500);
end
% plotting:
hold on
mark = 'xo*^dsp';
for k = 1:size(func_times,2)
    plot(1:size(func_times,1),log10(func_times(:,k).*1000),['-' mark(k)],...
        'MarkerEdgeColor','k','LineWidth',1.5);
end
hold off
xlabel('Log_2(Array size)','FontSize',16)
ylabel('Log_{10}(Execution time) (ms)','FontSize',16)
legend({'for','unique & for','tabulate','histcounts','accumarray','bsxfun','ndgrid'},...
    'Location','NorthWest','FontSize',14)
grid on
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The reason for this weird name comes from my field, Ecology. My models are a cellular-automata, that typically simulate individual organisms in a virtual space (the `M` above). The individuals are of different species (hence `spp`) and all together form what is called "ecological community". The "state" of the community is given by the number of individuals from each species, which is the `spp` vector in this answer. In this models, we first define a species pool (`X` above) for the individuals to be drawn from, and the community state take into account all species in the species pool, not only those present in `M`</sub>

Comment: If you unroll the for-loop in your `loop` function and replace it by a switch-case you get a balanced result  (ugly but hey it works). It is faster than `histcounts` for smaller array size but slower than `accumarray`. But it gets faster than `accumarry` and slower than `histcounts` for large array size. I used your code to verify this. However, the best result would be to use an if-else checking the size of `v` and then use either `accumarray` or `histcounts` since there is no overall best answer.

Comment: @solid What do you mean by _"replace it by a switch-case"_? to write a case for each element in `X`, like 500 cases?

Comment: Yeah Kind of. Ok writing 500+ cases is not fun (and also not efficient since unrolling to much slows your code down again, in general it is mostly a good idea even when it makes the code very ugly). You can write some cases, for example with 20 lines of  ‘spp(k+i) = sum(M==k+i);’ with ‘i=0:19’ and call this 25 times. It produces some overhead but will still be faster than just doing all 500 in one for loop.

Answer (score 5):

We know that that the input vector always contains integers, so why not use this to "squeeze" a bit more performance out of the algorithm?

I've been experimenting with some optimizations of the the two best binning methods [suggested by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38941695/3372061), and this is what I came up with:

- The number of unique values (`X` in the question, or `n` in the example) should be explicitly converted to an (unsigned) integer type.
- It's faster to compute an extra bin and then discard it, than to "only process" valid values (see the `accumi_new` function below).

[image: Though improvements are not large, it might be substantial when large datasets are involved.]

This function takes about 30sec to run on my machine. I'm using MATLAB R2016a.

---

```
function q38941694
datestr(now)
N = 25;
func_times = zeros(N,4);
for n = 1:N
    func_times(n,:) = timing_hist(2^n,500);
end
% Plotting:
figure('Position',[572 362 758 608]);
hP = plot(1:n,log10(func_times.*1000),'-o','MarkerEdgeColor','k','LineWidth',2);
xlabel('Log_2(Array size)'); ylabel('Log_{10}(Execution time) (ms)')
legend({'histcounts (double)','histcounts (uint)','accumarray (old)',...
  'accumarray (new)'},'FontSize',12,'Location','NorthWest')
grid on; grid minor;
set(hP([2,4]),'Marker','s'); set(gca,'Fontsize',16);
datestr(now)
end

function out = timing_hist(N,n)
% Convert n into an appropriate integer class:
if n < intmax('uint8')
  classname = 'uint8';
  n = uint8(n);
elseif n < intmax('uint16')
  classname = 'uint16';
  n = uint16(n);
elseif n < intmax('uint32')
  classname = 'uint32';
  n = uint32(n);
else % n < intmax('uint64')  
  classname = 'uint64';
  n = uint64(n);
end
% Generate an input:
M = randi([0 n],N,1,classname);
% Time different options:
warning off 'MATLAB:timeit:HighOverhead'
func_times = {'histcounts (double)','histcounts (uint)','accumarray (old)',...
  'accumarray (new)';
    timeit(@() histci(double(M),double(n))),...
    timeit(@() histci(M,n)),...
    timeit(@() accumi(M)),...
    timeit(@() accumi_new(M))
    };
out = cell2mat(func_times(2,:));
end

function spp = histci(M,n)
  spp = histcounts(M,1:n+1);
end

function spp = accumi(M)
  spp = accumarray(M(M>0),1);
end

function spp = accumi_new(M)
  spp = accumarray(M+1,1);
  spp = spp(2:end);
end
```

Comment: Very nice! in fact, in my models I use uint all the time, so I'm already taking advantage of that, but it's good that you pointed that out. I'm wondering what happens at array size 2^14, which seems to be a critic point for the comparison between `histcounts` and `accumarray`? Also, `histcounts` is still the best option for large data.

Comment: Also, just for fun, I have added another method to the answer.

Comment: @EBH I tried that `bsxfun` approach too, didn't mention it because it wasn't better. Perhaps I would come up with better ideas if it weren't for that "tish'a be'av" hunger... :P

Comment: Well, I have included it because I wanted to cover the various methods. Anyway, I think this is one of the most efficient ways to cope with the hungre ;)