# How to use the following code if larger sets of data are provided using matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix

I have written a code:

```
edge = linspace(botEdge, topEdge, numBins);
[N,ind] = histc(Speed, edges);
new = find(Speed>edges,1,'last'); 
N(new) = N(new)+1;
```

For example if I give speed value from data sets say 5.5 they, the `new` will tell you in which bin this value belongs and you can double check via looking the `edge` value you can see in which bin this value belongs. I tested with this value and I got correct result. You can also check via running this code with giving input

`Speed` is 3000x1, `edge` is 50x1, `N` is 50x1. This working perfectly for single value of `speed` but If I want to do same thing with my all `speed` data (3000x1) what should I do?

Comment: your code makes no sense, you have a for loop i, which is never used inside your loop, you have a vector called speed, and a vector edges in different length, how on earth do you expect to do Speed > edges? Please fix your code.

Comment: You cannot compare `Speed>edges` unless they are the same size or one of them is a scalar, and also it makes no sense. What are you trying to compare hare?

Comment: @EBH thank you for asking in kind way unlike others (being rude). yes it make sense because I want to know incoming speed data belongs to which bin and here edge is basically a difference between speed(2) -Speed(1) data. So with this edge I can able to see in whichbin this speed data belongs. I modified code written code also for more explanation please have a look :

Comment: Next time provide **all** relevant information when you first post the question, so you won't get a -4 downvote before you open your mouth...

Comment: @EBH thank you for your such advice, I will definitely keep in mind

Comment: Doesn't `ind` already give you this information? `ind` is the bin that each data point went into.

Comment: @beaker ind is bin no. I have use this to create my reference data and located my reference data on each bin.Now after that new point is coming and I have to find this new point belongs to which bin of reference data. And this can be done by finding the relationship between edge and new point.Hence I used find function to do this. If you understand the explanation please upvote the question

Comment: @beaker I used histc to create bin for my reference data and I want to relate that bin with my incoming data. So this can only be done via calculating edge hence I just use edge of my reference data with my incoming data,which gave me my answer (i.e incoming data going to which bin of reference data)

Comment: off course both data is different. reference data is for healthy system and incoming data is for unhealthy system. And Bin edges, specified as a vector. edges(1) is the left edge of the first bin, and edges(end) is the right edge of the last bin.  I hope this help you if not I would suggest you to please have a look into a function called histcount. there  they have explanation with examples

Comment: @beaker no friend I am sorry if you feel in that way... Since I am using comment section to explain you hence my explanation is limited here. Hence I told you to refer this site. if you feel I am being rude. My apology for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a compact but not the most efficient way to do this:

```
Speed = randi(99,3,1) % some arbitrary data
edge = linspace(1, 99, 50);
New = arrayfun(@(a) find(a>edges,1,'last'),Speed)
```

Example for output:

```
Speed =
    22
    41
    64
New =
    11
    20
    32
```

A `for` loop will be faster:

```
New = zeros(size(Speed));
for k = 1:length(Speed)
    New(k) = find(Speed(k)>edges,1,'last');
end
```

And here is another method:

```
New = sum(bsxfun(@gt,Speed,edge),2);
```

All of them yield the same output, it's up to you to check which is fastest under your conditions.

Comment: thank you for your support , I really appreciate your help...could you tell me why you said it is not efficient but  compact and could you suggest some efficient way to solve such problem...?

Comment: @Sujal it's just a matter of timing, If you deal with arrays in size 1*3000 it doesn't really matter, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941694/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-elements-in-an-array/) for more details.