# Vectorizing code - How to reduce MATLAB computational time

Tags: matlab, performance, time, cpu

I have this piece of code

```
N=10^4;
for i = 1:N
    [E,X,T] = fffun(); % Stochastic simulation. Returns every time three different vectors (whose length is 10^3).
    X_(i,:)=X;
    T_(i,:)=T;
    GRID=[GRID T];
end
GRID=unique(GRID);
% Second part
for i=1:N
for j=1:(kmax)
    f=find(GRID==T_(i,j) | GRID==T_(i,j+1));
    s=f(1);
    e=f(2)-1;

 counter(X_(i,j), s:e)=counter(X_(i,j), s:e)+1;
end
end
```

The code performs N different simulations of a stochastic process (which consists of 10^3 events, occurring at discrete moments (T vector) that depends on the specific simulation.
Now (second part) I want to know, as a function of time istant, how many simulations are in a particular state (X assumes value between 1 and 10). The idea I had: create a grid vector with all the moments at which something happens in any simulation. Then, looping over the simulations, loop over the timesteps in which something happens and incrementing all the counter indeces that corresponds to this particular slice of time.

However this second part is very heavy (I mean days of processing on a standard quad-core CPU). And it shouldn't. 
Are there any ideas (maybe about comparing vectors in a more efficient way) to cut the CPU time?

This is a standalone 'second_part'

```
N=5000;
counter=zeros(11,length(GRID));

for i=1:N
    disp(['Counting sim #' num2str(i)]);
    for j=1:(kmax)
        f=find(GRID==T_(i,j) | GRID==T_(i,j+1),2);
        s=f(1);
        e=f(2)-1;

        counter(X_(i,j), s:e)=counter(X_(i,j), s:e)+1;

    end
end

counter=counter/N;
stop=find(GRID==Tmin);
stop=stop-1;
plot(counter(:,(stop-500):stop)')
```

with associated dummy data ( filedropper.com/data_38 ). In the real context the matrix has 2x rows and 10x columns.

Comment: If this takes *days* I am almost sure that most of the time is from `fffun`. Try to profile your code with a small `N`

Comment: Are you pre-allocating `counter`?

Comment: @Adriaan unfortunately this is not the case. the first part takes less than a minute. in the second part there's no unallocated variable. :(

Comment: @AnderBiguri this is not the case. the first part takes less than a minute. :(

Comment: @horchler yes, i'm preallocating it.

Comment: I recommend that you check that the preallocation was done correctly and that `counter` is indeed not growing. Then you could look into vectorizing your double `for` loop. Use `profile` to see where the slowest parts are. Hard to say more without a runnable example (even with dummy data since the first part of the code is not the issue). You can also change the `find` to only look for the first two matches by adding a second argument.

Comment: Why do you need both `GRID` and `T_`? It looks like at the end of the first loop `T_==GRID.'`

Comment: @EBH maybe you're right, but the point is: the performance problem occurs in the last two nested loops.

Comment: @Surferonthefall I understand that, but I'm also trying to understand your code, so I can try to reproduce this problem. Nevertheless, writing a clearer code is alway better.

Comment: @horchler this is a working 'second_part' ( http://pastebin.com/0MCgkshY ) with associated dummy data ( http://www.filedropper.com/data_38 ). In the real context the matrix has 2x rows and 10x columns. I'm trying to enhance the code profiling but I've never done things like that. Could you please give me some hints? I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: @EBH you're right.. updated question

Comment: @EBH a bit of distraction, sorry! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I understand:

`T_` is a matrix of time steps from N simulations.
`X_` is a matrix of simulation state at `T_` in those simulations.

so if you do:

```
[ut,~,ic]= unique(T_(:));
```

you get `ic` which is a vector of indices for all unique elements in `T_`. Then you can write:

```
counter = accumarray([ic X_(:)],1);
```

and get `counter` with no. of rows as your unique timesteps, and no. of columns as the unique states in `X_` (which are all, and must be, integers). Now you can say that for each timestep `ut(k)` the number of time that the simulation was in state `m` is `counter(k,m)`.

In your data, the only combination of `m` and `k` that has a value greater than 1 is `(1,1)`.

---

**Edit:**

From the comments below, I understand that you record all state changes, and the time steps when they occur. Then every time a simulation change a state you want to collect all the states from all simulations and count how many states are from each type.

The main problem here is that your time is continuous, so basically each element in `T_` is *unique*, and you have over a million time steps to loop over. Fully vectorizing such a process will need about 80GB of memory which will probably stuck your computer.

So I looked for a combination of vectorizing and looping through the time steps. We start by finding all unique intervals, and preallocating `counter`:

```
ut = unique(T_(:));
stt = 11; % no. of states
counter = zeros(stt,numel(ut));r = 1:size(T_,1);
r = 1:size(T_,1); % we will need that also later
```

Then we loop over all element in `ut`, and each time look for the relevant timestep in `T_` in all simulations in a vectorized way. And finally we use `histcounts` to count all the states:

```
for k = 1:numel(ut)
    temp = T_<=ut(k); % mark all time steps before ut(k)
    s = cumsum(temp,2); % count the columns
    col_ind = s(:,end); % fins the column index for each simulation
    % convert the coulmns to linear indices:
    linind = sub2ind(size(T_),r,col_ind.');
    % count the states:
    counter(:,k) = histcounts(X_(linind),1:stt+1);
end
```

This takes about 4 seconds at my computer for 1000 simulations, so it adds to a little more than one hour for the whole process. Not very quick...

You can try also one or two of the tweaks below to squeeze run time a little bit more:

1. As you [can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941694/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-elements-in-an-array), `accumarray` seems to work faster in small arrays then `histcouns`. So may want to switch to it.
2. Also, computing linear indices directly is a quicker method than `sub2ind`, so you may want to try that.

implementing these suggestions in the loop above, we get:

```
R = size(T_,1);
r = (1:R).';
for k = 1:K
    temp = T_<=ut(k); % mark all time steps before ut(k)
    s = cumsum(temp,2); % count the columns
    col_ind = s(:,end); % fins the column index for each simulation
    % convert the coulmns to linear indices:
    linind = R*(col_ind-1)+r;
    % count the states:
    counter(:,k) = accumarray(X_(linind),1,[stt 1]);
end
```

In my computer switching to `accumarray` and or removing `sub2ind` gain a slight improvement but it was not consistent (using `timeit` for testing on 100 or 1K elements in `ut`), so you better test it yourself. However, this still remains very long.

---

One thing that you may want to consider is trying to discretize your timesteps, so you will have much less unique elements to loop over. In your data about 8% of the time intervals a smaller than 1. If you can assume that this is short enough to be treated as one time step, then you could round your `T_` and get only ~12.5K unique elements, which take about a minute to loop over. You can do the same for 0.1 intervals (which are less than 1% of the time intervals), and get 122K elements to loop over, what will take about 8 hours...

Of course, all the timing above are rough estimates using the same algorithm. If you *do* choose to round the times there may be even better ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. There's a substantial problem: when I perform the i-th simulation, things change only at timesteps.. so the j-th state keeps the same for all the T comprised between T_(i,j) and T_(i,j+1) (with this border excluded)... If you could solve this issue..

Comment: @Surferonthefall let me see if I get you right: in a specific simulation, you record all state changes, and the time steps when they occur. So the way to read `T` is the from time step `T(k)` to `T(k+1)` the simulation was in state `X(k)`. Now what you want is to align all those time vectors and for each unique **interval** count all the different simulation states. Correct me if I wrong, and let me get back to you with this...

Comment: yes!! exactly! just a note: the interval is **[** T(k); T(k+1) **[** (i.e. at T(k+1) the state is already changed; T(k+1) isn't included)....

Comment: @Surferonthefall see my edit. For your exact case, I don't think there is a very fast solution. However, see also me ending note there. You might want to consider some approximation. Hope this helps ;)