# Simultaneous multiple sums

Tags: matlab, octave

I am looking for a way to do multiple sums simultaneously and as fast as possible. Suppose

```
a       = [3 4 1 9 8 3 5];
indices = [1 1 2 1 2 1 2];
```

Then, the result should be a 1x2 array, say, `sumz` with

```
sumz = [19 14];
```

In other words, I sum every element of `a` with index 1, and put the result to `sumz(1).` Then, I sum every element of `a` with index 2, and put the result to `sumz(2).` and so on.

I know how to do this using `for` loops, `find`, etc. What I am looking for is a fast code.

Comment: Use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html?s_tid=doc_ta): `sumz = accumarray(indices(:),a(:)).'`

Comment: @EBH Thanks. I have not heard about that function before. It looks quite strong. Let me see if I can handle it using that.

Comment: @EBH Thanks. That does it. It also looks accumarray is not a script, but perhaps they did it in C, so it should hopefully be fast.

Comment: That is a "built-in" function, written in C or FORTRAN. And this is probably as fast as you can get. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941694/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: @EBH Alright; thank you.